# ZeroMQ with android: NoClassDefFoundError: org.zeromq.ZMQ

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, zeromq

I have a problem with getting ZeroMQ to work on android. I compiled everything into the .jar and .so file that i needed. Then I added `zmq.jar` to `/libs/` and the `libjzmq.so` to `/libs/armeabi/` and added the `.jar` to the build path. (`right-click -> build path -> Configure build path ... -> Libraries -> Add JARs...`)

I've also marked the .jar for export in the "`Order and Export`" tab and moved it to the top of the list, but i still get "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.zeromq.ZMQ`".

What else can I try?

I'm using Eclipse by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper answer to your direct question as I was unable to solve the same problem. Recently I came across JeroMQ on the mailing list and am now using it in an internal application for instant messaging. It is working very well but requires ZeroMQ 3.x. ZeroMQ is very easy to install so that should not be a blocking issue.

Take a look at the GitHub repo here:
https://github.com/miniway/jeromq

If you are using Git, you can add that as a submodule or you can simply pull the code and add it into your main app. I would highly recommend the former, but I ended up doing the latter simply to get my test app up and running easier.

Comment: If you use JeroMQ, get `0.3.0-SNAPSHOT` instead of `0.2.0` because it uses the `org.zeromq` namespace, so if you build your own language bindings later, your code will integrate with it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem too! The way it works for me is to set the package order in Preferences->Java Build Path->Orders and Export. Select the checkbox of zmq.jar, and click the 'up' button to make it in the first line in the list, then the error disappears happily, hope this would be helpful to you :)